# Need to include 0 in byte[]

Tags: c#

I am working on a compression algo in c#, and it requires me to break  an IntX number to byte[].

Now, the problem I am facing is :
this is the number : 
111100000222

when am breaking it to byte[], it breaks up as

```
byte[0] = 111
byte[1] = 100
byte[3] = 222
```

as you can see, it ignores all the 0's in the middle, which could have holded a byte

the correct byte[] should have come up as

```
byte[0] = 111
byte[1] = 100
byte[3] = 000222
```

is there any way,manipulation I can handle this, so I can pass my byte[] to the method, I want 0 to be considered too

Any help is highly appreciated

My method accepts this :

```
public byte[] REncode(IEnumerable<byte> data)
{
ResetEncoder(new EncodeModel(256));
foreach (byte b in data)
EncodeSymbol(b);
EncodeSymbol(model.EOF);
FlushEncoder();
return writer.Data;
}
```

Comment: i break up the number till the next number becomes more than a byte can hold.

so say, number is 12345
my byte[] will be
byte[0] = 123
byte[1] = 45

since byte[1] could not hold 1234, as it's more than 256, so I have to pass the remaining variables to next index
make sense?

Comment: @ShobhitMaheshwari show the method you're using to construct the byte[].

Comment: Try this https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/de8fssa4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This looks like a *really* weird way of representing numbers. What are you going to do if you get `333` as the number? Why are you focusing on *decimal* digits?

Comment: And why do you go from left to right?? Quite unnaturally..!

Comment: okay, this is how am converting string to byte[]

foreach (char c in compressedString)
                    {
                        data = data + c.ToString();
                        if (int.Parse(data) > 256)
                        { 
                            string newData = data.Remove(data.Length-1);
                            bytes.Add(byte.Parse(newData));
                            data = c.ToString();
                        }
                    }
            bytes.Add(byte.Parse(data));

Comment: Please add it to the question, not in a comment!!

Comment: "It ignores all the 00s.." - what* ignores them?? Why aren't you displaying byte[2] in either output? Did you make the function that is 'ignoring' them...? And no, byte3 should not contain 6 digits - byte[2] should contain the zero.

Comment: @ShobhitMaheshwari how could you store 000222 in a byte including the zeros on the left ?

Comment: step0: go from right to left!  step1: if the rightmost digit is 0 move to the next byte. step 2: test if the 2nd digit (from the right!) is a 0 and the 3rd form the right greater than 2; then move both to the next byte. step 3: test if the 3rd digit from the right is a 0, then move it to  the next byte. Done. Still: __verry weirrd__ Note: unless your zeroes are realy rare you shouldn't expect anything good in terms of compression; after all, you never know how many zeroes a byte=0 will hold. Hence it can only hold 1 zero. Better split in pairs throughout..

Comment: why not standard `BitConverter.GetBytes()` and `BitConverter.ToInt64()`?

Answer (score 0):

Based from what you write in your question and comments, there seems to be a major flaw with your algorithm. The value 000222 is equivalent to 222 as byte. One way to bypass that is to make your algorithm do as follows:

```
byte[0] = 111
byte[1] = 100
byte[3] = 000 // Is in fact 0
byte[4] = 222
```

This way when you build up you will get 11110000222, however, this is where the big flaw comes. Consider the 2 numbers 1002 and 100002. Your algorithm will give

```
byte[0] = 100
byte[1] = 002 // Is in fact 2
```

The above value is the same for both numbers, and when you build it up you will get 1000002 for both, not 1002 and 100002.